# Plant-based meat-like food producers?

Tags: meat-substitutes

Is there one place to get a list of all plant-based meat-like food producers?

This will help all those who want to shift from non-veg without compromising on taste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Wikipedia has such a list.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vegetarian_and_vegan_companies

Comment: that is a good start.

Comment: @Sandith You can add entries to the list if you think it is incomplete.

Comment: I meant, that it is a good info for beginners like me.